# Lumen Laravel issues with put and delete

Tags: lumen

Building an API application with Laravel Lumen. The GET (list) and POST (create) methods work fine, but I can't get PUT (update) and DELETE to work. For all testing I'm using the POSTMAN.

The route file contains:

```
$app->put('/project/{$id}', [
    'as' => 'project-update',
    'uses' => 'ProjectsController@update',
    function($id) {}
]);

$app->delete('/project/{$id}', [
    'as' => 'project-delete',
    'uses' => 'ProjectsController@delete',
    function($id) {}
]);
```

And the Controller is doing the following:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
    $project  = Project::findorfail($id);
    $project->name = $request->input('name');
    $project->description = $request->input('description');
    $project->completed = $request->input('completed');
    $project->save();

    return response()->json($project);
}

public function delete($id){
    $project  = Project::findorfail($id);
    $project->delete();

    return response()->json('deleted');
}
```

In POSTMAN, I'm using the PUT method for the Update action with a JSON body with some changed text. I'm using the DELETE method for the delete action but for both I always get a 405 Method Not Allowed

I know for forms you could use a hidden field, but as I just want an API, this is not relevant. Then I thought it had to do with X-CSRF-TOKEN, but tried for quite a while and could not solve it. Any idea's?

Comment: Why are you using `$` in your route definition variables? Change `{$id}` to `{id}`.

Comment: Thanks. That was indeed a mistake. I corrected it and got it to work. Thanks again.